# Plane dividing 4d space

Tags: geometry

I have a 4d space divided into 16ths about the origin. e.g. $(1,1,1,1)$ is contained in one 16th, $(-1,-1,-1,-1)$ is contained another, $(1,1,-1,-1)$ in a third.  If I add a plane to my 4d space, what is the maximal number of 16ths that my plane can pass through?

For example, if I have a 3d space divided into 1/8s, I am able to get a plane to pass through 7 of the 8 regions.  I'm not sure if this relates to the third row of Pascal's Triangle:

($\binom30+\binom31+\binom32 = 1+3+3 = 7$) or just a coincidence.

Comment: is your plane 2d of 3d?

Comment: could you please define explicitely what is a region.

Comment: plane is ax+by+cz+d=0

Comment: I can try - All regions meet at the origin of 4D-space.  The 4 separate axes divide the space into 2^4 regions.

Comment: Plane, or a hyperplane? For 2D, a hyperplane is a line; for 1D, a point.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to consider **hyperplanes** with a supplementary term, i.e., $ax+by+cz+dt+e=0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you divide $n$-dimensional space using $n$ hyperplanes ($n-1$ -dimensional subspaces; see the Wikipedia article on [hyperplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane) for more information), each perpendicular to an axis, and all intersecting at origin, you'll get $2^n$ cells defined by the hyperplanes.

In essence, you can label each cell by considering negative coordinates $0$, positive $1$ (choose either one for zero), and writing the valid ranges of each Cartesian coordinate axis as a binary number. For example, in 3D:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 z & y & x & \text{Binary} & \text{Decimal} \\ \hline
\lt 0 & \lt 0 & \lt 0 & 000 & 0 \\
\lt 0 & \lt 0 & \le 0 & 001 & 1 \\
\lt 0 & \le 0 & \lt 0 & 010 & 2 \\
\lt 0 & \le 0 & \le 0 & 011 & 3 \\
\le 0 & \lt 0 & \lt 0 & 100 & 4 \\
\le 0 & \lt 0 & \le 0 & 101 & 5 \\
\le 0 & \le 0 & \lt 0 & 110 & 6 \\
\le 0 & \le 0 & \le 0 & 111 & 7 \\
\end{array}$$

If you have more dimensions, just add new axes, and new binary digits. $n$ binary digits can represent exactly $2^n$ distinct values.

A hyperplane with all its normal components $\pm 1$ and slightly above or below the origin will pass through all but one cell; through $n^2-1$ cells.

If you have one dimension, you have $2^1 = 2$ cells. Each hyperplane is a point, and can be in either cell.

If you have two dimensions, you have $2^2 = 4$ cells. Each hyperplane is a line, and you can draw a line through three of the cells (diagonally, just above or below the origin).

If you have three dimensions, you have $2^3 = 8$ cells. Each hyperplane is a plane, and you can place it to intersect seven of the cells.

I do not have a mathematical proof of this. (If anyone does, I'd like to see it as a separate answer.) I do believe that a proof is possible using the
$$c_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i = 0$$
form, and enumerating the rules in which the hyperplane can pass through each cell. In particular, if $c_0 = -1$ and $c_i = 1$, the hyperplane cannot pass through the 0 cell (with all coordinates negative), but it does pass through all the other cells.